# Wordpress - How to show custom widget

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress.  I would like to create my own custom widget and display content on side menu.  However, wordpress isn't displaying the widget even though it shows in control pannel of wordpress.  I added the CustomWidget to the Primary Widget Area.

EDIT:  I noticed that the "widget" function isn't getting called, as it's suppose to be the one that do the rendering.

```
class CustomWidget extends WP_Widget{
    function CustomWidget(){
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'custom_widget', 'description' => __( "Custom Widget") );
        $control_ops = array('width' => 250, 'height' => 400, 'id_base' => 'custom-widget');
        $this->WP_Widget('CustomWidget', 'Custom Widget', $widget_ops, $control_ops);
    }

    function widget($args, $instance){
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? '' : $instance['title']);
        $menu_order = $instance['menu_order'];
        $show_siblings = $instance['show_siblings'];
        $exclude = $instance['exclude'];
        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title;
        echo 'Title!!!';
        echo $after_title;
        echo 'Content!!!';
        echo $after_widget;
    }
}

function CustomWidget_init(){
    register_widget('CustomWidget');
}
add_action("widgets_init", "CustomWidget_init");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your code

```
add_action('TB_RenderWidget', array('CustomWidget', 'render'),10,12 );
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.  CustomWidget constructor is being hit, just not the render function for some reason.

Comment: I forgot something. You need to include a function like this one `code` function render($before_widget,$after_widget,$title){
        echo $before_widget;
      
        if ( !empty( $title ) ) { 
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; 
        };

       //here you call whathever you use tu print content
        
       echo $after_widget;
    }`code`